# PowerShell will not run batch file on another machine

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a PowerShell script which sits on a VM. The script creates a PSSession and is meant to run a batch file that is sitting on a physical machine. However nothing is happening when I run the script.

**PowerShell:**

```
$Username = "Domain\User"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password*" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username, $password)
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "K2" -Credential $cred

Enter-PSSession -Session $session

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "K2" -ScriptBlock {
    Invoke-Expression -Command: "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe c/ 'cd C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-2.4.0\Go4Schools Tests\Test Runner'"
    Invoke-Expression -Command: "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe c/ 'START "" /wait PS_TR.bat'"

    #Invoke-Expression -Command: "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe Call c/ C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-2.4.0\Go4Schools Tests\Test Runner\PS_TR.bat"
}

Exit-PSSession
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

**PS Output:**

```
PS C:\> C:\Users\User\Desktop\PS_TR.ps1
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\User\Documents>
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\User\Documents>
```

When I run the below line in the `Invoke-Command` it successfully creates a folder on the physical machines desktop:

```
mkdir "C:\Users\administrator.HYPERSPHERIC\Desktop\NewFolder"
```

So I don't understand why the script is not running the batch file.

I have tried using the lines in the code above and the below:

- `Invoke-Expresson`
- `Invoke-Item`
- `Start-Process`
- `Start-Job`

I don't get any decent output as you can see from the above, and therefor I am finding it hard to debug.

Also running the batch file directly from the physical machine works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `Invoke-Expression`. It's [almost always the wrong tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/) for whatever job you have to do. Also, if you do `cmd /c cd ...` that changes the working directory *only for that one CMD process*. It doesn't affect the next CMD process you're starting.

Change this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "K2" -ScriptBlock {
    Invoke-Expression -Command: "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe c/ 'cd C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-2.4.0\Go4Schools Tests\Test Runner'"
    Invoke-Expression -Command: "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe c/ 'START "" /wait PS_TR.bat'"
}
```

into this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "K2" -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Location 'C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-2.4.0\Go4Schools Tests\Test Runner'
    & '.\PS_TR.bat'
}
```

And the problem will disappear.

Comment: With that I get the follow error `The term 'PSTR.bat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Comment: @Ross My bad. PowerShell doesn't include the current working directory in the PATH, so it must be `& '.\PS_TR.bat'`. Corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked. But leads me into another issues i will investigate. Thank you very much for your help.